# Is it a good practice to handle Authentication/Authorization errors using exceptions?

Tags: design-patterns, exception

If the application found that a user is not authenticated/authorized to do something, Is that an unexpected thing?

```
try {
    if (notAuth())
        throw new UnAuthException();
} catch (UnAuthException e) {
    Log . error(e);
    return false;
}
```

**if it is expected case** , so why there are so many frameworks have their own `UnAuthException` if failed Auth is not exception ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on scope.

In **business logic** layer "user is not authorized/authenticated" situation is exceptional, and should lead to runtime exception, for example (Java code):

```
public String salutation(User user) {
  // may lead to a runtime exception if user is not authorized
  return String.format("Hello, %s!", user.getName());
}
```

Implementation of `User` (it's an interface, of course) will either return user's name or throw a `NonAuthenticatedException` in `getName()`.

In **access control** layer user authorization/authentication status is processed as any other normal statuses, and should not be treated as exceptional situation, e.g.:

```
if (!user.isAuthenticated()) {
  httpResponse.addHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"secure content\"");
}
```

Comment: Thank you,yeh that's logic, but in the first example Business Logic , where should the exception be ? could you please expand the example by including the code that throw the exception and the code that handle it, sorry but I'm confused a little bit

Comment: I've updated my answer. `User` is an interface that will be implemented either with an authenticated user that returns its name from `getName()` or an anonymous user that throws an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a good practice to handle authentication\authorizations via exceptions because :

1) An exception is an anomalous situation that the system does not like and hence through exception handling
we are reacting to that situation. Authentication and Authorization exceptions are basically security violations i.e system
anomalies, and it is a good practice to to respond to violations. Exception handling framework is 
a popular mechanism to report violations\system anomalies and hence we use this framework to react to such situations.

That is why all popular frameworks(including .NET) have Auth. exception classes to encapsulate
errors.